# How to prepare a pretty-printed CSV from a mongodb shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am running a code like:

```
db.items.group({
    cond: {"id": {$in: [1,2,3]}},
    initial: {},
    reduce: function(item_data, out) { print(item_data.id + "," + item_data.price); }
});
```

I would like to have a CSV-formatted output of `id,price` pairs (for particular items). However, nothing is printed (except of an empty result of mapReduce). What is the right way to accomplish the mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.items.find({
    "id": {$in: [1,2,3]}
}).forEach(function(item_data) { print(item_data.id + "," + item_data.price); })
```